# How to save a Google Docs to PDF

Tags: google-drive, google-docs

I generally use Google Docs to create my documents and most of the time, I have to export it to PDF.

The problem is that sometimes I need to save this PDF in Google Drive.
So far, I do:

1. Download the document in: `File > Download As > PDF`.
2. Upload it to Google Drive

Is there an option in Google Drive to "Save as PDF" (without the need to download and upload the document)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As pointed out [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/K0WZ2aLRkFs/rSwFNHITEwAJ):

To "Save as PDF" instead of "Download as PDF", one should:

1. `File > Print`
2. Change destination to Google Drive

Not a straightforward assumption, but it works.

http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/K0WZ2aLRkFs/

Comment: Nice! But it seems to save to the Drive account which Chrome is logged into ... not the Drive account you're looking at. And it saves to the root, not the folder where the Doc resides.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can have the link to PDF version of the current document:

- Share the doc via link. You'll have link like this:
  https://docs.google.com/document/d/1au12_...mk5l1A/edit?usp=sharing
- Replace «/edit?usp=sharing» to «/export?format=pdf»

Now, this link will always point to PDF file with current version of the doc. The file will not be stored in the list of docs in the GDrive, but will be downloaded every time

Comment: This is awesome! How did I not know!

Comment: Note that this answer does not answer the question. The question says they're currently downloading a PDF version from a Docs document, but would like to export directly from the Docs document to their Drive (not download). This answer gives a URL syntax for downloading a PDF version from a Docs document, not export directly from the Docs document to their Drive.

Answer (score 0):

Crazy as it sounds, this feature is readily available in the **official Docs app** (Android)! 
There you can just save a PDF version in your Drive by having your file open and choosing `Export > Save as` from the menu (as one would expect...). You will find the PDF alongside your regular doc in the current folder.

No idea why things are so much more complicated when using the web interface.

---

(BTW, I'm not 100% sure of the exact name of the menu points as I'm using the app in German. But this should be close enough to get you there.)